# Marklogic rest resource extension deployment

Tags: marklogic

Is there a way to modify a xquery module & deploy it as multiple rest extensions on a http server? Rest resource name should be unique so that each developer can test xquery module changes on their dev machine.

The problem with using curl is that resource name should match the namespace in xquery module.

curl --anyauth --user ***:*** -X PUT     -H "Content-type: application/xquery" -d@"./dev-search.xqy"     "http://host:port/v1/config/resources/dev-search-v4?title=retrieval interface&version=1.0&provider=marklogic&description=This module returns MarkLogic document&method=get"

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have multiple developers using the same HTTP application server on the same MarkLogic instance to test their code as they are writing it. I think that's the problem you should solve.

First, look into having each developer use a local copy of MarkLogic. If that's not an option, I'd set up each developer with a separate application server and content database (with a small subset of data). Then each developer can deploy whatever and whenever he or she wants.

Once a developer is happy with a set of changes, they can be checked into git (or whatever) and deployed (automatically, using Jenkins, for instance) to an integration server.

You can use the [Roxy Deployer](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy) to manage multi-environment deployments like this.